# NumberPicker scaling gives strange appearance (Nexus 5X)

Tags: android, android-number-picker

I have 3 NumberPicker in my layout, like that:

```
<NumberPicker
     android:id="@+id/panel_first_number_picker"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

...
```

And I my fragment (onCreateView()) I set scale Y and X for these NumberPicker:

```
numberPicker1.setScaleX(0.9f);
numberPicker1.setScaleY(0.9f);
numberPicker2.setScaleX(0.9f);
numberPicker2.setScaleY(0.9f);
numberPicker3.setScaleX(0.9f);
numberPicker3.setScaleY(0.9f);
```

And Moto G4, Samsung S5, etc. there is no layout problem, but on Nexus 5X there are some **vertical grey lines**:

[image]

If I remove the scaling, it's OK. But I need to adjust size with setScale().
Do you have any explanation, guys?